# How to dynamically route pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How would I dynamically route each page without using app.get() everytime?
My code is also returning the 404 error code, also

```
console.log(page + " rendered");
```

wont work for some reason.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();


app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');


var pages = [
    'users', 
    'index'
];

pages.forEach(function(page) {
        app.get('/' + page, function(request, response) {
        response.render(page);
        console.log(page + " rendered");
    });
    console.log(page + " set up");
});

app.listen(80);
console.log('Express app started on port %d', 80);
```

Comment: So you want a quicker way to write all your route if the code inside is the same? Also, what is the error raised by your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression in your route. ^ and $ denotes start and end of the respectively. | denotes or. Regular expression for your requirement is `/^(users|index)$/`.

```
app.get(/^(users|index)$/, function (req, res, next) {
  response.render(req.params[0]);
  console.log(req.params[0] + " rendered");
});
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

This is the dynamic routing schema I'm using with express, you might be able to re-purpose it to suit your needs. It requires putting some "meta-data" into an array of objects (routes)

```js
"use strict";

let express = require("express");

let routing = (req, res) => {
    let router = express.Router(),
    // "meta-data" for routes
        routes = [{
            path: "/",
            view: "default",
            title: "root"
        }, {
            path: "/otherpath",
            view: "otherfile",
            title: "otherpage"
        }];
    // iterates through routes looking for req.path
    let routeIndex = routes.findIndex(route => route.path === req.path);
    // if object in routes found with matching path
    if (routeIndex >= 0) {
        // serves content
        res.status(200).render(routes[routeIndex].view, {
            title: routes[routeIndex].title
        });
    } else {
        // else 404s
        console.log("404 from request: ", req.path);
        res.status(404).sendFile(process.cwd() + "/views/404filename.htm");
    }
    return router
};

module.exports = routing;
```

Comment: I've edited the code in my response to use findIndex() instead of for..of since I'm using es6 syntax anyway. This ends up being cleaner and more robust (no more having to prevent server side 404 reporting)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a new route for each page, you probably want to look up the view for the url dynamically.  Make sure to call `next()` if you don't handle the path from within your handler so that further routes and/or middleware is called.

```
var routes = {
    '/users': 'users rendered',
    '/index': 'index rendered',
}

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    let view = routes[req.path]
    if (!view) 
        return next()
    res.render(view)        
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send('404 - Not found')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use('/', function(req, res) {
  // whatever
});
```

This will match everything. Inside the callback, you can do your rendering (you can access the request via the `req` object to render the appropriate page). See [app.use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: app.use('/) will only match the root url.